# Сглаживание текста в Firefox

Tags: html, css, шрифты, text

Как сгладить кастомные шрифты в Firefox под Windows?

Firefox 42.0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Chrome 47.0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую вариант:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004);
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
font-smooth: always;
```

но в firefox не работает..
Есть ли еще какие-то способы забороть эту проблему?

Comment: Можно попробовать: transform: scale(.99).

Comment: @NeedHate, сложно сказать помогло бы или нет, но вчера сглаживания не было, сегодня уже есть, firefox не обновлялся..
видимо firefox глючил